# Naive question on the reflection principle - Random walk theory

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, self-learning, random-walk

I have a rather naïve question about the **reflection principle** and I wanted to be sure, if my understanding is correct.

> *[Feller page 70].* The number of paths from $A(a,\alpha)$ to $B(b,\beta)$ which touch or cross the $x$-axis equal the number of paths from $A'$ to $B$.

*Proof.* Let $t$ be the abscissa of the first such vertex, where $s_a>0,\ldots,s_{t-1}>0,s_{t}=0.$ The particle first hits the $x$-axis at epoch time $T(t,0)$. The sections $AT$ and $A'T$ being reflections of each other, there exists a one-to-one correspondence between all paths from $A'$ to $B$ and such paths from $A$ to $B$ as have a vertex on the $x$-axis. The lemma is proved.

The example figure 2. in Feller's book shows a path, that touches the $x$-axis, $k=1$ times. I mocked up another blue path, that crosses the $x$-axis several times; below. Sections $AT$ and $A'T$ are reflections about the $x$-axis.

Question. The geometric argument [Feller] still holds true, because, in principle, **the same logic can be applied to each section isolated**, between the crossings from the negative to the positive region and vice versa. ***Every blue path maps to a unique green path.*** Is my understanding broadly correct?

[image]